# How can I see other network computers?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

My IPS uses a "PPPoE" type internet connection, which lets me see other computers on the same network when I click on the "Network" icon on the desktop.

This happens when I connect directly using that connection.

But when I use my router, and connect to my wireless network (which uses that PPPoE connection), I can't see the network computers anymore :(

So can I have the network thingy in wireless mode as well?

PS:

- In the "Network and Sharing Center" all my networks are set to "Public".
- File and Printer sharing is enabled

Answer (score 1):

Your router will give you an IP address which is not routable on the Internet.  It uses Network Address Translation (NAT) to map that address onto its IP address so you can access the Internet.  However, by default it does not map incoming connections nor the traffic required to access Windows Shares.

System using Windows network sharing use broadcast announcements to locate each other.  These do not get transmitted to the network.  Using Network shares on the Internet is not secure.  Those systems that you can see may be Honeypots, or are systems which are insecurely connected to the Internet.  Some of them may contain malware which may infect your system.

Malware infected systems are believed to be responsible for the vast majority of Spam.  These operate in networks known as botnets.  Why pay for hundreds or thousands of machines, when you can use infected machines for free?